# how to add a dependecy to a system library in my conanfile .py?

Tags: c++, linker, conan

My ConanFile.py for TWSAPI's C++ code

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools

IBKR_VERSION = "10.18.01"

class TwsApiConan(ConanFile):
    name = "twsapi"
    version = IBKR_VERSION
    license = "NA"
    url = "URL_TO_CODE_FORK"
    description = "Built from a mirror of the actual TWS API files in Github"
    topics = ("tws", "interactive brokers")
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False}
    generators = "cmake"

    def source(self):
        self.run("git clone --depth 1 --branch " + IBKR_VERSION + " git@github.com/tws-api.git")

        tools.replace_in_file("tws-api/CMakeLists.txt", "         LANGUAGES CXX )",
                              '''         LANGUAGES CXX )
add_compile_options(-std=c++17)''')

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(source_folder="tws-api")
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="tws-api/source/cppclient/client")
        self.copy("*.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.so", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dylib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["twsapi"]
```

Recently TWSAPI added a requirement for an obscure library.. which I have installed locally and linked in an downstream project.. but does it make sense to move that dependency into this ?  I tried the following but don't see any change or signal that the libs were picked up.. is it merely my job to find them and add them under self.copy as well?

Conan References : https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/8044#issuecomment-726053437

Debian Package containing the libs : https://packages.debian.org/sid/libintelrdfpmath-dev

```
    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["twsapi", "bidgcc000"]   <--- merely calling it out doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`self.cpp_info.system_libs`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#cpp-info):

```py
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["twsapi"]
    self.cpp_info.system_libs = ["bidgcc000"]
```

Comment: thank you, I have added this now to the recipe.. but still my project is not building in Rust via conanrs and CXX .. but I will mark your answer as correct since it seems valid for conan https://github.com/dtolnay/cxx/issues/1132